# Derivation of neutrino oscillation phase factor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, neutrinos, electroweak

As we know, the neutrino $\nu_{\alpha}$ with flavor $\alpha=e,\mu,\tau$ is a linear combination of mass eigenstates:
$$
 |\nu_{\alpha}\rangle=\sum_iU_{\alpha i}|\nu_i\rangle,\quad i=1,2,3
$$
where the propagation of the mass eigenstates $|\nu_i\rangle$ can be described by plane wave solutions:
$$
 |\nu_{i}(t)\rangle = e^{ -i ( E_{i} t - \vec{p}_{i} \cdot \vec{x}) }
 |\nu_{i}(0)\rangle.
$$
Suppose that $t=T$ and $|\vec{x}|=L$. Then the phase factor can be given by
$$
 \begin{split}
  E_iT-p_iL &= E_i\frac{L}{\sqrt{1-m_i^2/E_i^2}}-\sqrt{E_i^2-m_i^2}L \\
  &=E_iL\left(1+\frac{m_i^2}{2E_i^2}\right)-E_iL\left(1-\frac{m_i^2}{2E_i^2}\right)
   +\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{m_i^4}{E_i^3}\right) \\
  &=\frac{m_i^2L}{E_i}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{m_i^4}{E_i^3}\right)
 \end{split}
$$
However, this result is not correct. The artilce [Neutrino oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation) on Wikipedia says that
$$
 |\nu_{i}(L)\rangle = e^{ -i m_{i}^2 L/2E }|\nu_{i}(0)\rangle
$$
which differs in a factor of $1/2$. I can't figure out what is wrong with my derivation above (Maybe the formula for time interval $T$ is not correct, but I am not sure). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the PDG Review provided by user12262, I found another article [Quantum Theory of Neutrino Oscillations for Pedestrians - Simple Answers to Confusing Questions](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0505141) which is instructive on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then the phase factor can be given by [...] $\frac{m_i^2L}{E_i}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{m_i^4}{E_i^3}\right)$

The calculation as shown in the question statement above seems correct to me.
But it's not the whole story ...

> [...] a factor of $1/2$

The appearance of this factor $\frac{1}{2}$ along with the difference $\Delta~m^2_{jk} := m^2_j - m^2_k$ has been motivated in various ways, according to the (recent) [PDG Review article on neutrino mixing (ch. 13)](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/reviews/rpp2013-rev-neutrino-mixing.pdf).

The quickest way to make it plausible seems to calculate the [interference (or beat) of two waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_%28acoustics%29) (of equal amplitude):

$$e^{i \phi} + e^{i \theta} = \left( e^{ \frac{1}{2} (i \phi - i \theta) } + e^{ \frac{1}{2}~ (i \theta - i \phi) } \right) \times e^{ \frac{1}{2}~ (i \phi + i \theta) } = 2 ~ \text{Cos}[ \frac{1}{2} (\phi - \theta) ]  \times e^{ \frac{1}{2}~ (i \phi + i \theta) }.$$

Substituting "*phase factors*" as calculated above results in the phase difference

$$\delta \phi_{jk} := \frac{1}{2}~ \left( \frac{m_j^2 L}{E_j} - \frac{m_k^2 L}{E_k} \right)$$

which in "realistic experimental situations" due to $E \gg m ~ c^2$ becomes to good approximation (for a suitable "mean energy" $E$) the more familiar

$$\delta \phi_{jk} \simeq \frac{1}{2}~ \Delta~m^2_{jk}~ \frac{L}{E}.$$

The remaining "high frequency factor" $e^{ \frac{1}{2}~ i~ \left( \frac{m_j^2 L}{E_j} + \frac{m_k^2 L}{E_k} \right) }$ may apparently be considered and treated as a "usual single particle phase factor".

Finally a note on terminology:

> the neutrino $\nu_{\alpha}$ with flavor $\alpha = e, \mu, \tau$ is a linear combination of mass eigenstates [...] $

When referring to quarks or to charged leptons, the word "[flavor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_%28particle_physics%29)" is synonymous to "*mass eigenstate*".
I find it at least unfortunate and confusing if this convention isn't followed when referring to neutrinos; and, in correspondence with the terminology used for quarks, I prefer to call $\nu_e, \nu_{\mu},$ and $\nu_{\tau}$ "weak (eigen-)states" of neutrinos (which couple by electro-weak interaction to the charged leptons of the indicated flavor: $e, \mu,$ or $\tau$).

Comment: Thank you very much. From the PDG, the time interval $T$ can be related by $T=L/\bar{v}$, where $\bar{v}$ is the ''average'' velocity. But why it cannot be treated as constant?

Comment: soliton: "_Thank you very much._" -- You're welcome; and thank you for preparing your question. "_[...] ''average'' velocity. But why it cannot be treated as constant?_" -- I found [Andrew G. Cohen, Sheldon L. Glashow, and Zoltan Ligeti (2009). "Disentangling neutrino oscillations". Physics Letters B 678: 191](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4602) pretty instructive on this point: It disabused me of some naive preconceptions regarding "velocity of a neutrino". (The link is also [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation) which is why I looked at it today ...)